# Check if a string had been hyperlinked

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

What regular expression should I use to detect is the text I want to hyperlink had been already hyperlinked.

Example:

I use

```
$text = preg_replace('/((http)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i', '<a href="\\0">\\0</a>', $text);
```

to link regular URL, and

```
$text = preg_replace('/[@]+([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/', '@<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
```

to link Twitter handle.

I want to detect whether or not the text I'm going to hyperlink had been wrapped in `<a href=""></a>` already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, replace the regular URLs first, as it won't affect anything starting with an `@` cause no URL starts with an `@`. Then replace the twitter handles.

That way you don't need to detect if it's been hyperlinked already.

Comment: Thanks for great idea. Is there a script that I can remove the linked URLs/Twitter usernames? I've tried regular expression myself, but no success yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an answer but another possible solution; You could also search to see if the starting a element exists

```
$text = '<a href="#">here</a>';
if (gettype(strpos($text, "<a")) == "integer"){
  //<a start tag was found
};
```

or just strip all tags regardless and build the link anyway

```
$text = '<a href="#">here</a>'; 
echo '<a href="my-own-url">' . strip_tags($text) . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strpos($str, '<a ') !== FALSE) echo 'ok';

else echo 'error';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = '<a href="#">Stephen Ou</a>';

$str = 'Stephen Ou';

if (strlen(str_replace($str, '', $html)) !== strlen($html)) {

    echo 'I got a feeling';

}
```